# Compiling for windows on cygwin/mingw

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin, mingw

So, I'm trying to compile a simple C example for the cairo graphics library in cygwin.
When compiling for cygwin, everything works as expected, but for windows it compiles, but doesn't work when trying to execute.

This is my makefile:

```
CFLAGS= -lcairo

#WIN32HEADERS= /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/cairo
WIN32HEADERS= /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/cairo -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/glib-2.0 -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mlib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/pixman-1 -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/freetype2 -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/libpng16 -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/freetype2 -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/libpng16

#WIN32LIBS= ./lib32
WIN32LIBS= ./usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin

#WIN64HEADERS= /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/cairo
WIN64HEADERS= /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/cairo -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/glib-2.0 -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mlib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/pixman-1 -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/freetype2 -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/libpng16 -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/freetype2 -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/minclude/libpng16

WIN64LIBS= ./lib64
#WIN64LIBS= ./usr/x86_64-w64-mingw64/sys-root/mingw/bin

CYGWINHEADERS= /usr/include/cairo
CYGWINLIBS= /usr/bin


all:
    i686-w64-mingw32-gcc kairo.c -o kairo_32.exe -I $(WIN32HEADERS) -L $(WIN32LIBS) $(CFLAGS)
    x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc kairo.c -o kairo_64.exe -I $(WIN64HEADERS) -L $(WIN64LIBS) $(CFLAGS)
    gcc kairo.c -o kairo.o -I $(CYGWINHEADERS) -L $(CYGWINLIBS) $(CFLAGS)

#Build for Windows 32 Bit
win32:
    i686-w64-mingw32-gcc kairo.c -o kairo_32.exe -I $(WIN32HEADERS) -L $(WIN32LIBS) $(CFLAGS)

#Build for Windows 64 Bit
win64:
    x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc kairo.c -o kairo_64.exe -I $(WIN64HEADERS) -L $(WIN64LIBS) $(CFLAGS)

#Build for Cygwin - maybe linux in general?
cygwin:
    gcc kairo.c -o kairo.o -I $(CYGWINHEADERS) -L $(CYGWINLIBS) $(CFLAGS)

#delete everything but the source files
clean:
    rm *.exe
    rm *.o
```

I've tried the commented out parts, as well as the currently active parts, but no luck.
When trying to execute the resulting .exe, I get an error that libcairo-2.dll is missing, but shouldn't it be able to find it since it's linked?
And is there any way to link to the needed dll's in a non-system folder? I can't quite figure out how to do that.

Comment: all is very simply - system can not found `libcairo-2.dll`. place it for example in same folder, where exe. `but shouldn't it be able to find it since it's linked?` - of course no

Comment: Alright, that did in fact resolve the error for this particular dll - I'll just repeat that with the rest, until I don't get any more errors. But what should I pass the compiler so I can put the dlls into a subfolder of my project?

Comment: @RbMm it works now that every required dll is in the same directory as the exe - could you just post your comment as an answer so I can upvote you?

Comment: what the relationship between *compiler* (!!) and dlls into a subfolder !? even *linker* here absolute unrelated. you not need and cannot pass something to compiler or linker for this. if exe require not system dlls - the task of installer place all dlls, where it will be found. usual this is same folder where exe located. of need add *PATH* variable to system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The import lib is located at

> /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libcairo.dll.a

so you need to define

> WIN32LIBS=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib